# Not able to access functional component variable in return in react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I want to display the error variable declared in the useState by accessing it in return, but it throws the error `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined".`

This is what I have tried so far.

```
    Const Login = () => {
    let history = useHistory();

    const [form,setForm] = useState({
        email:'',
        password:'',
        error:''
    })

    const handleSubmit = async(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        let a = await login(form);
        console.log(a);
        if(typeof a !== "undefined") {
            history.push('/Trial')
        }
        else {
             this.state.error = "Invalid Email or Password";
        }
        console.log('Logged in')
        console.log(e);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
                <title>Sign In</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css"></link>
            </head>
                <body>
                    <div className="container1 bg">
                        <div className="forms-container">
                            <div className="signin">
                                <form className="sign-in-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                    <h2 className="title">Sign In</h2>
                                    <div className="input-field">
                                        <i className="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" onChange={(e) => setForm({...form, email: e.target.value})}/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="input-field">
                                        <i className="fas fa-lock"></i>
                                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={(e) =>setForm({...form, password: e.target.value})}/>
                                    </div>
                                    <button class="btn1 solid">Login</button>
                                    <p class="social-text" style={"color: red"}>{this.error}</p>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
)
```

Comment: There is no `this` in functional components. Thats what `useState` is for.

Comment: Replace this.state.error with form.error

Comment: @SlothOverlord thank you! I am now able to access the variable, but I want to display it only when the login credentials are wrong. The error variable is initially null and will get the value only if it enters the else block in the login component. But that doesn't seem to be happening.

Comment: Can you share the login(form) code?

Comment: import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import "firebase/auth"
import {auth} from './firebase'
  
export const login = async({email, password})=>{
    try {
      const res = await firebase.auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      console.log(res);
      return res.user;
    }
    catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    
}        @SlothOverlord

Comment: @SlothOverlord Sorry for the bad indentation. New here!